# GCC - Initialize automatically pointers during compilation time

Tags: pointers, gcc, initialization

Is there a flag to pass to gcc or g++ that make it automatically initialize any pointers during compilation time, like setting pointers to NULL before starting generating code.

Comment: I don't think so. Besides, why not do it right and simply handle initialization yourself? Or kick it up a notch, use C++ and employ an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: Any problem with just initializing pointers when declaring? Then you don't need to worry about compiler support for something like that.

Comment: libMudFlap is not exactly what you ask, but still might be useful to you somehow...

Comment: A pointer that's initialized to NULL is no better than a pointer that has a random value in it.  It's still garbage until you do something with it.

Comment: @AndyLester Are you saying that you never initialize variables? Or that you magically write your code so that you can always initialize to a good and usable value?

Comment: It's not magic.  It's good practice.  If you don't initialize your variables, then they are garbage.  It doesn't matter if that value is zero or whatever happens to be on the stack.  The contents are still garbage.

Comment: @Andy, I would say that a null-initialised pointer *is* marginally better than an uninitialised one, simply because it can be tested correctly for the null value. You can at least accurately detect that it points to nothing so should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Like many other compilers, they assume, in the interest of maximum speed, that you know what you're doing :-)

If you *want* your pointers initialised to null, you should do that explicitly, with something like:

```
myType *myVar = nullptr; // or NULL for C
```

Of course, C++ offers a variety of smart pointers which can do this for you:

```
std::unique_ptr<myType> myVar; // will be null
```

and this simply ensures it's null in the constructor of the pointer itself.

In fact, you should consider *any* raw-pointer code in C++ to be a potential flaw, there's almost *no* reason to use them in the modern language.